# Adding images to select option tag in html in hierarchical structure

Tags: jquery, html

I have to add images in hierarchical way in select option tag. Have got some ways but that do not fulfill my need i.e. hierarchical representation. Links I went through are :
 http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/selectmenu/index.html and
http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/

Comment: you didn't specify what exactly is you need which is not fulfilled by the URLs you have provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have got excellent link that fulfilled my task. Actually its not select option but through css and javascript such effect have been given. http://www.givainc.com/labs/mcdropdown_jquery_plugin.htm